# Are there any savoury dishes using matcha tea?

Tags: culinary-uses, tea

I know that you can use matcha powder in a similar way to chocolate in sweet foods but are there any savoury dishes you can make with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trend I've seen recently is **making tea broths/sauces for meats, fishes**, etc...  Besides being a good use for tea, this has the **double effect of giving off the tea's natural aroma** when presented to the eater as opposed to simply using the tea to crust a meat - where you wouldn't really get any tea flavor until you actually bit in.

I've also seen people **smoking meats with tea leaves** and such.  I haven't tried this myself to see if the results are worth the trouble (aka - if you can actually taste the tea flavor).

I would also try **poaching various items in a matcha tea poaching liquid**.  For example:

1. Water
2. Sugar + salt
3. Matcha tea powder
4. Peppercorns
5. Bay leaves
6. Whatever else sounds good to you.

You could use this to poach chicken and fish.

Lastly, don't be afraid to **add it to soups**!  Carrot-ginger soup would benefit from the addition of some matcha powder.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to mix it in your fried chicken flour/spice mix, dredge it well, and serve with a sesame/mustard dip, or something with a little Asian flare.

Comment: 1+ sounds interesting

Answer (score 2):

I've made a green tea and garlic cream sauce using matcha, which I thought was pretty nice. It's tricky to pull off, as I learned when someone tried my imprecise steps transcribed and found the result "bland", but I came to the conclusion that it was likely a difference in the amount of salt used.

Matcha-iri Genmaicha, which is a toasted rice green tea that has additional matcha powder for flavor, is sometimes used in ochazuke, a post-drinking food that typically involves a bowl of rice with tea or soup stock poured over, topped with pickles or other flavorful ingredients (furikake, sliced nori, some other things).

Additionally, for a few years, matcha flavored salts were popular in Japan as an accompaniment to tempura. I've bought them or just mixed very finely grained salt with matcha.

I wrote about [matcha salt and the green tea cream sauce years](http://blog.jagaimo.com/archive/2005/07/31/matcha-cuisine.aspx) ago on my blog.

Answer (score 1):

A classic Japanese snack is [chazuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chazuke), which is green tea poured over rice. I imagine that it's usually made with lower grade tea, but a matcha might lend some interesting texture to the rice.

Answer (score 0):

You can dig though [these](http://foodgawker.com/?s=matcha+&cat=0) (also google) for more, but [this](http://invitadoinviernoeng.blogspot.com/2010/06/matcha-noodles-with-basil-cream-and.html) looked good.

I've used it in pastries and quick breads before ([these](http://une-deuxsenses.blogspot.com/2010/03/matcha-pancakes.html) pancakes were good).

Comment: It might be worth summarising the link content in the answer for usability and to keep the answers relevance if the links become broken

Answer (score 0):

You can check out recipes at Matcha Natural www.matchanatural.com/recipes
they post a ton of helpful recipes including Matcha tea, 
also for green tea noodles, pasta, rice etc.

[Matcha Natural Recipes](http://www.matchanatural.com/recipes)
[Matcha Natural Baked Recipes](http://matchanatural.com/matcha-natural-baked-recipes)

Comment: Dear user20678, welcome to the site! We appreciate your contribution, but we generally discourage link-only answers, because they 1) look like spam, and 2) are susceptible to link rot. If you can summarize the content of the links in a few sentences, we will keep the answer, but else we will have to delete it.